# stdout , stderr and logging using the script command

Tags: scripting, logs, stdout

I have `remove.sh` which contains:

```
rm -v test.tmp
```

And I have `install.sh` which contains:

```
script remove.log -c './remove.sh'
```

What can I do so that whether or not `test.tmp` exists, I don't see any `rm` related messages on the screen but see `removed 'test.tmp'` or `rm: cannot remove 'test.tmp': No such file or directory` in `remove.log` which the script command produces?

Answer (score 2):

If your question is, "how do I suppress stderr output from a command", the answer will be something along the lines of:

```
command 2> /dev/null
```

This will redirect stderr (aka file descriptor 2) to `/dev/null`, which simply discards anything it receives.

However, the `rm` command supports the `-f` flag, which will prevent it from producing an error message if the file does not exist:

```
$ rm file_that_does_not_exist
rm: file_that_does_not_exist: No such file or directory
$ rm -f file_that_does_not_exist
$
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but no. I don't want to suppress stderr. I just want to hide it from showing up on the terminal but want it logged in my log file.    -f flag won't work either as again i need to see the error in the log file.

Comment: In that case, you want `script -c remove.log 'your command' > /dev/null`.  The `script` command will capture `stdout` and `stderr` to your log file, and the redirection will suppress all terminal output from the `script` command.

Answer (score 1):

`script` is overkill for this. Yes it works, but thats not what script was made for. Script is used for applications which access the TTY directly, and dont use STDOUT/STDERR.

You can easily accomplish this with basic shell redirection.

```
./remove.sh &> remove.log
```