# selective stdout , stderr and logging using the script command

Tags: bash, scripting, logs, stdout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show only stderr on screen but write both stdout and stderr to file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9646/show-only-stderr-on-screen-but-write-both-stdout-and-stderr-to-file)
>   [stdout , stderr and logging using the script command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32000/stdout-stderr-and-logging-using-the-script-command)

cat test.sh:

```
rm -v foo.tmp
date
pwd
```

cat test2.sh:

```
script bar.log -c './test.sh'
```

When executing test2.sh I would like to see the following for example on my terminal:

```
Fri Feb 17 18:04:30 PST 2012  
/home/me/me
```

However in bar.log I would like to see:

```
removed 'foo.tmp'  
Fri Feb 17 18:04:30 PST 2012  
/home/me/me
```

or (in case foo.tmp does not exist)

```
rm: cannot remove 'foo.tmp'  
Fri Feb 17 18:04:30 PST 2012  
/home/me/me
```

Is this doable?

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult to do directly because `script` collects all the output on a temporary terminal and displays that appears on that terminal on its own standard output.

In `test.sh`, you need to have some way to distinguish the messages you want on the terminal from the messages you only want in the transcript. For example, add a prefix to each line indicating its importance level. As the other lines in your example don't start with `@`, I'll just prefix non-essential (transcript-only) lines with `@`.

```
rm -v foo.tmp | sed 's/^/@/'
date
pwd
```

And in the wrapper script:

```
script bar.log -c './test.sh | grep -v "^@"'
```

I don't think you can do much better without modifying the `script` utility. (If you want to go that route, I think the simplest method would involve a few lines of `expect`.)